# Counts of Quadrature Encoder

Tags: mobile-robot, quadrature-encoder

Simply, I had Rover 5 with 2 DC motors and 2 quadrature encoders, I just want to use encoders to measure the distance of travelling for each wheel.

To start with, I just want to determine the total counts per revolution. I read the article about quadratic encoder from [this broken link](http://letsmakerobots.com/node/24031).

In Rover 5, each encoder has four wires: red (5V or 3.3V), black(Ground), yellow (Signal 1) and white (Signal 2). I connected each wire in its right place on Arduino Uno board, using the circuit:

- rotary encoder ChannelA attached to pin 2
- rotary encoder ChannelB attached to pin 3
- rotary encoder 5V attached to 5V
- rotary encoder ground attached to ground

For one encoder, I test the code below to determine the total counts or ticks per revolution, the first program by using loop and second by using an interrupt.

Unfortunately while I run each program separately, rotating the wheel 360 degree by hand, the outputs of these two programs was just "gibberish" and I don't know where is the problem . Could anyone help?

Arduino programs posted below.

First program:

```
// Constants
const int  ChanAPin = 2;    // pin for encoder ChannelA
const int  ChanBPin = 3;    // pin for encoder ChannelB

// Variables
int encoderCounter = -1;   // counter for the number of state changes
int ChanAState = 0;         // current state of ChanA
int ChanBState = 0;        // current state of ChanB
int lastChanAState = 0;     // previous state of ChanA
int lastChanBState = 0;    // previous state of ChanB

void setup() {
  // initialize the encoder pins as inputs:
  pinMode(ChanAPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ChanBPin, INPUT);
  // Set the pullup resistors
  digitalWrite(ChanAPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ChanBPin, HIGH);

  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Serial.println("Rotary Encoder Counter");
}

void loop() {
  // read the encoder input pins:
  ChanAState = digitalRead(ChanAPin);
  ChanBState = digitalRead(ChanBPin); 
  // compare the both channel states to previous states
  if (ChanAState != lastChanAState || ChanBState != lastChanBState) {
    // if the state has changed, increment the counter
      encoderCounter++;
      Serial.print("Channel A State = ");
      Serial.println(ChanAState);
      Serial.print("Channel B State = ");
      Serial.println(ChanBState);      
      Serial.print("State Changes = ");
      Serial.println(encoderCounter, DEC);
    // save the current state as the last state, 
    //for next time through the loop
    lastChanAState = ChanAState;
    lastChanBState = ChanBState;    
  }
}
```

The second program (with interrupt)

```
static long s1_counter=0;
static long s2_counter=0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  attachInterrupt(0, write_s1, CHANGE); /* attach interrupt to pin 2*/
  attachInterrupt(1, write_s2, CHANGE); /* attach interrupt to pin 3*/
  Serial.println("Begin test");
}

void loop()
{
}

void write_s1()
{
  s1_counter++;
  Serial.print("S1 change:");
  Serial.println(s1_counter);
}

void write_s2()
{
  s2_counter++;
  Serial.print("S2 change:");
  Serial.println(s2_counter);
}
```

Comment: I would not expect any interrupt routine to have a serial print in it. If your interrupt is waiting around to send to a serial port, it is probably missing subsequent interrupts. This could easily account for gibberish data. As a quick check, your `_counter` values should never differ by more than 1 for a quadrature encoder. I would try removing the print statements, and have your `loop` function print the `_counter` values if they change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely getting something analogous to "[contact bounce](http://www.opencircuits.com/Debouncing_Microcontroller_Inputs)".
When you slowly rotate the wheel,
there are regions where channel A is Lo for a while,
then channel A is Hi for a while.
While it would be nice if the Arduino only saw one low-to-high transition
between those regions,
often a encoder will oscillate a few or a dozen times
during the brief period when the encoder is balanced on the edge of the transition.

Have you noticed that the original code always increments the counter, never decrements it?
If you had code that
handled both forward rotation (clockwise; incrementing the counter) and reverse rotation (counterclockwise; decrementing the counter),
it would automatically fix the "bounce" problem.

One popular approach: while B is low, low-to-high transitions on A increment the count,
while high-to-low transitions decrement the count.
Then if A bounces a few extra times while B is low --
instead of a crisp Lo-Hi (+1), it does Lo-Hi-Lo-Hi-Lo-Hi (+1, -1, +1, -1, +1) --
we still get the correct final count.
In either case the final result is one count more.
(While B is high, low-to-high transitions on A decrement the count, etc.)

A quick Google search
https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+quadrature+encoder+library
shows many quadrature encode libraries for the Arduino.
Many of them are reviewed at
http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/RotaryEncoders
.

Could you maybe try one of those libraries and tell us how well it worked (or didn't work) ?

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.